# Dynamic query (Current date) via web services in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

In my project we are consuming the company's data via Web Service REST. Today we don't do the query dynamically by passing the start date and end date parameters via string.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBqRx.png)

My goal is for the end date to update dynamically. I've already created a query that takes the current date but I can't put it in the parameter without generating an error in the query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IprEC.png)

This is the error message I get when I put the column value in the parameter:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYLhf.png)

I'm pretty sure I'm getting the syntax wrong. Anyone who can help me, I really appreciate it. I would like to point out that the date format for the API call to work is DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using

```
PutYourOtherTableNameHere[Hoje_Coluna]{0}
```

instead of

```
[Hoje_Coluna]
```

?

To see if that will work, put this in right before your query, then click on the step and see what it returns.

```
x = PutYourOtherTableNameHere[Hoje_Coluna]{0},
```

Comment: I changed for ""value"":'"Today[Today Column]{0}&"',
He catch the value, but they show "invalid json"

Comment: I assume you need another & in there  somewhere ...   ""value"":'"&Today[Today Column]{0}&"',

Comment: Sorry. I wrote it wrong here. 

I did this way: ""Value"":'"& Today[Today Column]{0}&"',

Power bi shows: "invalid json"

Comment: whats is the full code"? I assume ""valor"":""30/12/2021""  has to become 
""valor"":""" &Today[Today Column]{0}& """

Comment: FULL Code:

Csv.Document(Web.Contents("http://189.x.6x.2x:7xxx/int3xx/wsConsultarListagem.rule?sys=MTL&codigoListagem=x&codigoHash=4f9c125&parametros=[{""tipoDado"":""data"", ""valor"":""10/03/2022""},{""tipoDado"":""data"",""valor"":"""&Hoje[Today]{0}&""",}]"),[Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=1, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])

Comment: I find the error!

The comma in this part of code is incorrect: Hoje[Today]{0}&""",

Thanks!